# Azure Pipelines: building a C++ project with outside "Include Directories"

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

I tried searching with as many different terms as I could and couldn't find exactly what I'm looking for.
I have a C++ Project developed in Visual Studio 2019 and I am trying to build and deploy it in Azure Pipelines. It uses **Boost** and **OpenCV**. I skipped trying to include these in Azure Artifacts because of a rabbit hole with Azure CLI errors that took me almost half a day.

So it seems that there is a task to publish pipeline artifacts in the .yml file. How do I do this when my project needs to reference a certain directory, instead of one specific file or .dll? Here are images for how this is configured in Visual Studio:

[include directory for boost image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0YFz.png)

[include directory settings for opencv image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QebE.png)

Edit: Still trying, see my comment. Thinking about switching over to CircleCI.

Comment: I revisited this lately. It is still not working. Here is what I have done: 1.) Set up a custom Azure Pipeline Agent on my local machine 2.) Use that agent to do my builds 3.) Most importantly, pay attention to MSBuild arguments in the VSBuild task. I can not seem to get the proper arguments though. I tried something like: /p:IncludePath="c:\\opencv\\build\\include";$(IncludePath) /p:LibraryPath="c:\\opencv\\build\\x64\\vc15\\lib";$(LibraryPath)

Answer (score 0):

I found out what to do. Hopefully no one else wastes as much time as I did.

The key was MSBuild. One needs to first find out the values of $(IncludePath) and $(LibraryPath) by doing the following first in Visual Studio:

1. Right-click on your project, choose "Properties"
2. Go to the Build Events tab, and click "Pre-Build Event"
3. Click on and expand the Command Line row, and click "Edit"
4. Now click the button that says "Macros>>"
5. You will see a bunch of different variables and their values. Find the values for LibraryPath and IncludePath, copy and past them into a text file.

Now, assuming you already set up a local agent, follow these steps:

1. Put the text file in the root folder of where your agent is installed. For me, this was "C:\agents"
2. Have the first line be "LibraryPath=value" and the other line be "IncludePath=value". Use double slashes for the directory paths.
3. Rename the file to .env. If the agent is currently running, restart it so it can read in the environment variables it will use during your build.
4. In the MSBuild task of your pipeline, specify arguments. For my case, it was simply this: /p:IncludePath="C:\Program Files\boost_1_77_0;$(IncludePath)" /p:LibraryPath="$(LibraryPath)"
5. Run the pipeline. You can check your completed build on the local machine. For me, the path it kept going to was "C:\agents_work\2\s"